# Pip install not working on windows

Tags: python-3.x

I have python 3.6.2 installed and when I go to command prompt and type in pip install I get an error message that says "pip" is not recognized as an internal or external command; operable program or batch file. What should I do?

Comment: Can you tell us more about how you installed py3.6.2 and what version of Windows?

Comment: installed python from python.org/downloads on windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Add python and pip to windows path variables from as following [image]